# Why is my or operator not working in my while loop

Tags: java, operators

Im trying to use an or operator the the parameters of my while loop and its not working.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Checkpoint203P5 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String inputString;
    String letter;

    inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Y or N", "Not case sensitive");
    letter = inputString;

    while(!inputString.equals("Y" || "N")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter Y or N. \n       Please try again",  "Warning", 2);
        inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Y or N", "Not case sensitive");
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for participating");
    System.out.println("End of Job");
}
    
}
```

I tried replacing the || with + but then it made it so that I have to put "YN" or it would be invalid.

Comment: `"Y" || "N"` is not a valid expression in Java - `||` requires boolean operands like in `string.equals("Y") || string.equals("N")`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `||` operator cannot be used between strings as you attempted. The `||` operator is used for performing logical disjunction (OR) between two boolean expressions. It cannot directly work with strings.

In your original attempt:

```
while (!inputString.equals("Y" || "N"))
```

the expression "Y" || "N" is not valid in Java because the || operator expects two boolean expressions (or boolean values) on its left and right sides.

Instead, you need to compare each string separately using the || operator:

```
while (!inputString.equals("Y") && !inputString.equals("N"))
```

This expression checks if `inputString` is different from `"Y"` and different from `"N"`. If it is, the loop will continue to execute. If `inputString` is equal to `"Y"` or `"N"`, the loop will stop.

***Little offtopic:***

In JavaScript, the logical operator `||` can be used with "truthy" expressions, including strings. When you use the `||` operator between two expressions, it returns the first "truthy" expression. If the first expression evaluates to "truthy" (not `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, or an empty string `''`), then that expression will be returned, and the second expression will not be evaluated.